# sorting through a nominal data set by variable type

Tags: r

I am trying to sort through a nominal dataset which contains binary and ordinal data.

In order to perform univariate analysis on just the binary data, does anyone know a package/command that can help me parse through just binary data?

Thank you!

Trying to perform univariate logistic regression, and parsing through variables to determine p values individually. Anyone know how to parse (I have the for loop to do the univariate analysis already)

Comment: Hello lorrsto. To ask in stackoverflow you must at least post a minimal reproducible code example.

Comment: @RicVillalba The problem is I don't have code! I'm asking if anyone has suggestions for what I could try/if people have suggestions

Comment: If you have a dataset, please share it (i.e. `dput(head(dataset, 20))` output for a sample of 20 fst elements)  so anyone can deliver an answer based in that example. Also an expected output example would be useful. Otherwise an answer that can help you and other users is unfeasible.